# as3 dynamic TextField words from array placed into individual MovieClips into a sentence

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to create a dynamic sentence from an array of words. The words need to be placed next to each other in a sentence. I need the words to be in a movie clip so I can drag them as well.

Below is the code I am using but I can not get the words to go in sequential order according to the width to get a well formed sentence. For example there will be a lot of extra space between words or incorrect space and they overlap. Any ideas on how to get them one right after another on the x position?

```
package com.sentances {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.text.*;
    import flash.events.*;


    public class Main_Sentances extends MovieClip {


        public var Sentance: Array;
        public var myText: TextField;
        public var myMovie: MovieClip;

        public var Words: Array = new Array("This", "is", "my", "sentance.");

        public function Main_Sentances() {
            // constructor code

            MakeWords();
        }


        public function MakeWords() {
            var xSpot = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < Words.length; i++) {
                //trace(Words[i]);

                myMovie = new MovieClip();
                myMovie.name = Words[i];
                addChild(myMovie);

                myText = new TextField();
                myText.selectable = false;
                myText.border = true;
                myText.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat('Verdana', 50, 0xffffff);
                myText.text = Words[i];

                //trace(myText.name);

                myText.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, handleChng);
                myMovie.addChild(myText);               







                function handleChng(e: Event): void {
                    trace("childMC ADDED_TO_STAGE");
                        trace(myText.textWidth);

                        if(i==0)
                        {
                        myMovie.x = 0;
                        myMovie.width = myText.textWidth;
                        myMovie.height = myText.textHeight;
                        xSpot = myText.textWidth;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        myMovie.width = myText.textWidth;
                        myMovie.height = myText.textHeight;
                        xSpot = xSpot + myText.textWidth;
                        myMovie.x = xSpot;
                        }
                }

            }




        }


        // End Package  
    }
}
```

Comment: "Having many issues" elaborate.

Comment: Thanks Neal. I just added an edit. Thank you.

Comment: Could you stick with uniform width font? Then you could count the number of characters in the word and make the parent mc width be a factor of that and then put one word at the end of the previous word. Does that strategy sound usable? If so I can try to write up an answer that does that, but maybe with that idea you can take it from here?

Comment: Yes, I can stick with a uniform font. At times I may like to change the font size. Will that matter?

Comment: Font size should be fine. It looks like you have the right idea trying to set the mc width to the text width. But you also need to first set the textwidth to fit the text perfectly. Once you do that it should work better. Should be pretty easy to google that. I'll see what I can find too

Comment: First of all, you need to enable auto-sizing:  textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT; Then, if you want to read the resulting text size use can use:  var width:Number = textField.textWidth; var height:Number = textField.textHeight;

Comment: This method should allow any font style as well I believe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to let textfield's width auto fit the text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024615/how-to-let-textfields-width-auto-fit-the-text)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to enable auto-sizing:

```
textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
```

Then, if you want to read the resulting text size use can use:

```
var width:Number = textField.textWidth;
var height:Number = textField.textHeight;
```